# Changing font size to percent in theme

Tags: 7, theming

I want convert font size in existing theme from px to percentage. The [theme](http://demo.zymphonies.com/free-theme/software-responsive-theme/index/) and the [CSS](http://demo.zymphonies.com/free-theme/software-responsive-theme/index/sites/all/themes/software/css/stylee683.css). Should I change font-size in body and headers only, or better to change font size in all places in CSS? What is the correct way to specify font-size in percent in this particular CSS?

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 160%;
  color: #666;
  font-size:13px;
  background: #fff;
}

h1 {font-size: 18px;}
h2 {font-size: 16px;}
h3 {font-size: 14px;}
h4 {font-size: 13px;}
h5 {font-size: 13px;}
h6 {font-size: 13px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect place to use `em` instead of `px` for your font sizes. Change the font size in your `body` to `font-size: 13px;` or something, whatever size you want to be your standard size font.

Then, for all of the other elements, you can use `em` to adjust the size of the font based on percent. For example, `font-size: 1.5 em;` would be 1.5x larger than the standard size of 13px, and `font-size: 0.5 em;` would be 0.5x the size of the standard of 13px;

Comment: So I should leave `body` `font-size` as is, in pixel(13px), and adjust font-size for the other elements based on `em`? 13px is a bit small to me, and paragpaph font size is inherited from body.

Comment: You can change body font-size to whatever pixel size you want, and that will become your standard font size. Then all of the other fonts will be sized relative to that.

Comment: So setting body font-size to **em** relative unit will not provide any benefits here?

Comment: That is correct.